# Using Visibility Widget in Flutter to toggle widgets display

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, visibility, flutter-animation

I have a Column widget I'd only like to make visible when a user taps on the add new button. I am using the [Visibility widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) Flutter provides and I am using setState() to change the *visible* property in the Visibility widget class. It doesn't work.

What could I be overlooking? Find my code snippet below:

```
bool _addNewTax = false;

FlatButton.icon(
    color: kBgCircleColour,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    icon: Icon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.plusSquare,
      color: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _addNewTax = true;
      });
        Visibility(
          visible: _addNewTax,
          child: _buildTaxInputFields(),
        );
    },
    label: Text(
      'Add new tax',
      style: kRegularTextStyle,
    ),
  );
```

My _buildTaxInputFields function as below:

```
      _buildTaxInputFields() {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: inputValue,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                onSaved: () {},
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'tax name e.g. VAT, service charge, etc'),
                ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: inputValue,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                onSaved: () {},
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'tax percentage e.g. 20, 19.5'),
                ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    title: Text('I\'ll bear it '),
                    value: TaxBearer.merchant,
                    groupValue: _taxBearer,
                    onChanged: (TaxBearer value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _taxBearer = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: RadioListTile(
                      title: Text('Push to customer'),
                      value: TaxBearer.customer,
                      groupValue: _taxBearer,
                      onChanged: (TaxBearer value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _taxBearer = value;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
```

Comment: Don't put the `Visibility` widget inside `onPressed` function. Put it in the widget tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your visibility widget will never be rendered because you're generating it in the onPressed method of a button.
You could use a column to generate it below the button like this:

```dart
bool _addNewTax = false;
Column(
  children: [
   FlatButton.icon(
    color: kBgCircleColour,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    icon: Icon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.plusSquare,
      color: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _addNewTax = true;
      });
    },
    label: Text(
      'Add new tax',
      style: kRegularTextStyle,
    ),
  ),
  Visibility(
    visible: _addNewTax,
    child: _buildTaxInputFields(),
  ),
 ],
);
```